# how to make two build triggers to work one after the other

Tags: build, triggers, jenkins-plugins

I have job A and job B. Job B will be triggered by Job A. However we do not want job B to start if there is no code change in job B. We would use the "Poll SCM" build trigger.

How can we make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refrased question: Job A must trigger job B, but job B must only run when there are SCM changes for job B. How to configure this?

So, job A and job B have different code bases, but are somehow related and thus, the dependency between the jobs exists. The [Downstream-Ext](http://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream-Ext+Plugin) plugin can do this: it supports "extended configuration for triggering downstream builds: trigger build only if downstream job has SCM changes".

Comment: that's not my question. My question is after job A triggered job B, I still want to use another trigger - Poll SCM- in job B, meaning if no code changes in B, no build of B. Your answer seems to be whether A triggers B or not.

Comment: OK, didn't quite get that from the initial question. No problem.
So, job A and job B have different code bases, but are somehow related and thus, the dependency between the jobs exists?

In that case, this plugin might be useful for you: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Downstream-Ext+Plugin. It claims to support "extended configuration for triggering downstream builds: trigger build only if downstream job has SCM changes".

Comment: If that doesn't help, this plugin might also be worth taking a look at: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Multijob+Plugin

Comment: actually I had figured out that. the Downstream-Ext Plugin works exactly as I expected. I should have done deeper research before opening this question. Update your answer, I'll vote for you.